# Use typescript generic with class member type

Tags: typescript, generics

```
interface MyState {
  balances: { [address: string]: BN };
}

const [ state, setState ] = useState</* what should I do? */>({});
```

I want to pass type of MyState.balances to useState's generic type like `useState<typeof MyState.balances>({})`, but it didn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen didn't work. ts(2693) error occurred.
'MyState' Only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
interface MyState {
  balances: { [address: string]: BN };
}

const [ state, setState ] = useState<MyState['balances']>({});
```